# git checkout command does not take the file name in csh script

Tags: git, shell

I have made a test script BBB containing as below 
(it's for backup and restore of temp files for convenience).

```
#!/bin/csh
if ($argv[1] == 1) then

cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkid.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkidP.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2fsck.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2p/e2p.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/ext2fs.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/kernel-jbd.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuid.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuidP.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp include/libbb.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp include/platform.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_
cp scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h  ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_

else if ($argv[1] == 2) then

git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkid.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkidP.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2fsck.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2p/e2p.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/ext2fs.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/kernel-jbd.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuid.h
git checkout e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuidP.h
git checkout include/libbb.h
git checkout include/platform.h
git checkout scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h

else if ($argv[1] == 3) then

cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/blkid.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkid.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/blkidP.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkidP.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/e2fsck.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2fsck.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/e2p.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2p/e2p.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/ext2fs.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/ext2fs.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/kernel-jbd.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/kernel-jbd.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/uuid.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuid.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/uuidP.h e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuidP.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/libbb.h include/libbb.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/platform.h include/platform.h
cp ~/bkup/Evac_BUSYBOX_/dialog.h scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h

endif
```

When I run BBB 2, it gives me

```
-------------------------------------
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkid.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/blkid/blkidP.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2fsck.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/e2p/e2p.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/ext2fs.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/ext2fs/kernel-jbd.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuid.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'e2fsprogs/old_e2fsprogs/uuid/uuidP.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'include/libbb.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'include/platform.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/dialog.h' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

But when I run the git checkout commands directly on shell prompt, it runs ok.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your current directory is set correctly when running script.